# Changing CSS Rules with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

This is my css:

```
#firstWheel {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: -52%;
    display: none;
}
```

I want to pass these others with JS after a I press the button.

```
#firstWheel{
  display: block;
  animation-name: pos;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes pos {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
}
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Which is the best way to pass lots of properties. Is it possible to pass all in one `DOM` manipulation?

Comment: Use classes instead of id values for CSS rules, and then change classes as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Using classes and toggling them with JS would be a better approach however its possible to achieve this with JS

```js
const firstWheelStyle = document.createElement("style");
firstWheelStyle.innerHTML = `#firstWheel {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: -52%;
    display: none;
}`;
document.head.appendChild(firstWheelStyle);
const changeCssBtn = document.getElementById("changeCss");
changeCssBtn.onclick = () => {
  firstWheelStyle.innerHTML = `#firstWheel{
        display: block;
        animation-name: pos;
        animation-duration: 1.5s;
      }
      
      @keyframes pos {
        0% {
          transform: scale(0);
      }
        100% {
          transform: scale(1);
        }
      }`;
  changeCssBtn.onclick = null; //Just claring off click event since it needs to run only once.
};
```

```css
#firstWheel{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
  }
```

```html
<div id='firstWheel'></div>
<button id='changeCss'>change css</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in your js function you can do something like and just like @Pointy said just now, use classes instead of id for CSS rules if can

```
function changeClass(){
   var div = document.getElementById('id of the element');
   div.classList.add('class name','class name 2',...);
}
```

Hope it helps! and also pls help leave comment if there is any wrong with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can add new class to your element when the button is clicked. But you need to override current css rules with `!important`

```js
$("#myButton").on("click",function(){
  $("#firstWheel").addClass("animation");
})
```

```css
#firstWheel {
    position: relative;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    display:none;
}

.animation {
  display: block !important;
  animation-name: pos;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes pos {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
}
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='firstWheel'></div>
<br>
<button id='myButton'>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use toggleClass function as in example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp